# How to convert pixel locations to gps points?

Tags: python, geolocation, gps, pixel

I have a Geo-tagged aerial image, that is it contains the latitude, longitude and altitude at which the image was captured. I am using this image to plan a route for a ground robot to move between two points. I got this route as pixel coordinates, however, now i want to convert these coordinates to real world GPS points. I am writing my code in python. I found out that the GDAL library could be of help.
Sample image showing the path between two points. The axis represents the pixels' coordinates.
[image: Sample image showing the path between two points. The axis represents the pixels' coordinates]

Comment: This is too broad, but at the very least you're going to need one additional data point: a second set of geographical coordinates, or an orientation and scale. Knowing that pixel X has latitude Y and longitude Z gives an infinite number of possibilities. (Imagine spinning the image around your known point while at the same time zooming in and out.)

Comment: @Chris If I know the GPS coordinates of the starting and ending points. Is there way I can get the coordinates of the path?

Comment: I think that would be enough, yes, but your question is still probably too broad for SO. Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes for the basic trigonometry. You'll probably need translation and scaling, too. And that's just the regular flat part—as Wouter van Nifterick says, in reality, you'd need to consider the round shape of the planet as well as the fact that lines of longitude aren't parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have the coordinates of the corners.

If the image spans a small area (until a few kilometers), you could simply interpolate.

I'm mentioning that it only works for small distances, because this disregards the fact that the earth is not flat. Once you're working with larger distances, you'll have to know more about the used projection.

Comment: That also assumes that the image's axes are (roughly) aligned with the latitudinal and (non-linear) longitudinal axes. If it's rotated things get a lot tricker.